# Reflect cell value change in one column into another column calculation - Datagrid WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a datagrid with three columns as shown below:

[image: Datagrid]

Datagrid is populated via an observable collection.

View model is defined as:

```
public class PlanningResult : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    public double A { get; set; }
    public double B { get; set; }
    public double D { get; set; }
}

ObservableCollection<PlanningResult> populatePatternData = new ObservableCollection<PlanningResult>();
public ObservableCollection<PlanningResult> PopulatePatternData
{
    get { return populatePatternData; }
    set
    {
        populatePatternData = value;
        base.OnPropertyChanged("StringList");
    }
}
```

In the datagrid, user is allowed to modify cell values of column A. I am able to achieve that from UI but how do I reflect the cell value change in column D  when cell value in A changes?

Here is the XAML:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="PrintReport" ItemsSource="{Binding PopulatePatternData}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="A" Binding="{Binding A,StringFormat={}{0:0.00}, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" IsReadOnly="False"  />
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="B" Binding="{Binding B,StringFormat={}{0:0.00}, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" IsReadOnly="True" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="D" Binding="{Binding D,StringFormat={}{0:0.00}, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" IsReadOnly="True" />
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: BTW:  is this a typo? OnPropertyChanged("StringList");  
Don't should be just OnPropertyChanged();
?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Raise the `PropertyChanged` event for the `D` property in the setters of the `A` and `B` properties:

```
public class PlanningResult : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private double _a;
    public double A
    {
        get { return _a; }
        set { _a = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); NotifyPropertyChanged("D"); }
    }

    private double _b;
    public double B
    {
        get { return _b; }
        set { _b = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); NotifyPropertyChanged("D"); }
    }

    public double D { get { return _a + _b; } }
}
```

Also note that the `Mode` of the read-only properties should be `OneWay` which is the default value:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="D" Binding="{Binding D,StringFormat={}{0:0.00}}" IsReadOnly="True" />
```

Comment: If I want to initially populate "D" with a set of values before user starts to make changes in A or B, can that be done? @mm8

Comment: I get error about "property" being read only if I try to fill column D with values via collection !! @mm8

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42271975/datagrid-error-viemodel-property-cant-be-populated-c-sharp-wpf/42272106#42272106

Answer (score 1):

I have a generic pattern for this situation:
you define the formula component with normal properties as usual, and in the *dependent* property - in your case `D = A + B` you'll write only the getter.

Then you take each component of the formula - in this case `A` and `B` - and you go to their setters and simply add the `OnPropertyChanged` of the formula - `D` - after the `OnPropertyChanged`of its components - `A` and `B`.

That's because the formula changes *if and only if* its components do: that explains where the notifications must be sent from.