# Datagrid error - Viemodel property can't be populated

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a datagrid with four columns:

[image]

Datagrid is populated via an observable collection. View model is:

```
public class PlanningResult : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    public double A { get; set; }
    public double B { get; set; }
    public double C { get; set; }
    public double D { get; set; }
}

ObservableCollection<PlanningResult> populatePatternData = new ObservableCollection<PlanningResult>();
public ObservableCollection<PlanningResult> PopulatePatternData
{
    get { return populatePatternData; }
    set
    {
        populatePatternData = value;
        base.OnPropertyChanged("StringList");
    }
}
```

Here is the requirement for me:
- `Column C` and `Column D` should have same values unless user makes a change in `Column A` or `Column B` . In that case, `Column D` should become `ColumnA+ColumnB`.

Based on the above condition, I can make changes in the view model as

```
public class PlanningResult : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private double _a;
    public double A
    {
        get { return _a; }
        set { _a = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); NotifyPropertyChanged("D"); }
    }

    private double _b;
    public double B
    {
        get { return _b; }
        set { _b = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); NotifyPropertyChanged("D"); }
    }

    public double D { get { return _a + _b; } }

public double C {get;set;}
    }
```

- The issue that I face is that I am unable to populate columnD with "`initial values = values same as columnC`". How do I provide initial values to the column D?
- When I try to do it via collection, I get an error as :

**`property D cannot be assigned to -- it is read only`**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a setter to the `D` property and set its value in the setter of the `A` and `B` properties:

```
public class PlanningResult : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private double _a;
    public double A
    {
        get { return _a; }
        set { _a = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); D = _a + _b; }
    }

    private double _b;
    public double B
    {
        get { return _b; }
        set { _b = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); D = _a + _b; }
    }

    private double _d;
    public double D
    {
        get { return _d; }
        set { _d = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public double C { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: thnks. A variant of the problem: Is it possible to call a function when A or B is varied that does something? @mm8

Comment: You could call any method you want in the setters of the A and B properties just like you call the NotifyPropertyChanged method.

Answer (score 1):

You could use another field to store whether `A` or `B` has been changed.

```
private bool hasAorBChanged = false;
```

This field can be set to true once `A` or `B` have changed.

```
private double _a;
public double A
{
    get { return _a; }
    set { _a = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); NotifyPropertyChanged("D"); 
    hasAorBChanged = true;}
}

private double _b;
public double B
{
    get { return _b; }
    set { _b = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); NotifyPropertyChanged("D"); 
    hasAorBChanged = true;}
}
```

Then the property D could look like

```
public double D { get { return hasAorBChanged ? _a + _b : C; } }
```

Not the cleanest solution, but given that D is meant to be read-only, this should work.

Edit: You may also move the `hasAorBChanged = true;` to the method `NotifyPropertyChanged()`. It would make it little cleaner.